# Prism making my contenteditable div in right-to-left

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

So basically i'm using prism syntax highlighter and I have put `contenteditable` on the div. If there is a tag displayed in the div when I press a key it is inserted at the start of the div. This is my code:

```
<head>
  <title>
    Syntax highlighting test
  </title>
  <!-- Prism JS -->
  <script src="pe.js"></script>
  <!-- Prism CSS -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="prism.css">
</head>
<body>
  <pre id="hello-world"><code id="kdh" class=" language-html line-numbers" contenteditable onKeyUp="Prism.highlightAll();">&lt;h1h>HIHI&lt;/h1></code></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: [Implement this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) it might help.  -  on second thought, it's because you're re-firing that prism function everytime and that re-inserts the div to the DOM (or changes it).  You need to make your event handler more complex to disable once `click` and re-enable `onblur`.

Comment: @Deryck I did this adn now when there is a line break it is destroyed

Comment: When you say line break do you mean an actual line break (like in the displayed code before clicking to edit) or do you mean a carriage return (as in you pressed the enter key after you started editing)?

Comment: @Deryck a carraige return

Comment: You have to attach a handler the return `keypress` event (which is just the `keypress` overall that you check the value of) and `e.preventDefault()`.  I actually did this exact thing in a fiddle a while ago let's see if I can find it again

Comment: Found it - http://jsfiddle.net/yKSZV/ the only part you need to look at is the `on('click'...'focus'...blur...` stuff.  PS - you'll need to continue debugging WITH this code - this isn't going to end your issue necessarily, it's just showing how to capture the return key event and go from there